# svd of a VERY LARGE sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, bigdata, svd

I have a `75000` x `75000` sparse matrix, and I'm interested in computing the full `SVD`. Whenever I use:

```
[U,D,V] = svds(A,k)
```

I get an out of memory error for `k` larger than `200`. Is there a tracable way for computing the matrices `U`, `V` and `D` in this case?

Comment: [Download More RAM](http://downloadmoreram.com/).

Comment: What @rubenvb is trying to say is "no".  The `svds` will return `75E3` x `k` matrices, which will be extremely large memory-wise if `U` and `V` are not sparse (and I think they are usually dense for large systems).

Comment: @rubenvb, thanks for that link! I'll upgrade my computer right away! Do you happen to know where I can download a new fan too?

Comment: The question you need to ask is: Do I need the SVD or can I do the same thing somehow else?

Comment: Yes. basically I'd like to know whether there are ways to get an approximate SVD so that U and V are sparse. Has there been work on a SVD where the singular vectors are sparse? If so, is there a clean MATLAB implementation of the same? .

Comment: @rubenvb too bad they don't let me download more than 4gigs

Answer (score 0):

The approximate matrix decomposition into a product of three matrices is called [CUR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUR_matrix_approximation). However I'm not sure the matlab contains its implementation.